# How can I force disable the dependency conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is the any manual brute force way to fix the conflict issue ?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bson":
  In Gemfile:
    mongo (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bson (= 1.11.1) ruby

    bson_ext (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bson (~> 1.11.1) ruby

    mongoid (~> 4.0) ruby depends on
      moped (~> 2.0.0) ruby depends on
        bson (~> 2.2) ruby
```

Comment: Sometimes it works to delete your Gemfile.lock, and run `bundle`, but I suspect this is just the first in a long line of weird errors, due to your somewhat unconventional setup. It might be better to try to address the actual issue, rather than an issue created by a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force a gem to use an incompatible dependency version. But you can try to update all gems and bundler will try to adjust the dependencies for you.

Update all gems: `bundle update`

Update a group of specific gems: `bundle update mongo mongoid bson bson_ext`